# Why doesn't this division work in Python?

Tags: python, numbers

Consider:

```
>>> numerator = 29
>>> denom = 1009
>>> print str(float(numerator/denom))
0.0
```

How do I make it return a decimal?

Comment: Somewhat an aside, but `float` is not the same as the `Decimal` type in the Python standard library.  When you say "I just want it to return a decimal" what you really mean is "I just want it to return a string representing a fractional value in decimal notation", right?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Until version 3, Python's division operator, /, behaved like C's division operator when presented with two integer arguments: it returns an integer result that's truncated down when there would be a fractional part. See: [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/doc/2.2.3/whatsnew/node7.html)

```
>>> n = 29
>>> d = 1009
>>> print str(float(n)/d)
0.0287413280476
```

In Python 2 (and maybe earlier) you could use:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> n/d
0.028741328047571853
```

Comment: -7//3 = -3 (remainder is = 2) in Python and -7/3 = -2 (remainder = -1) in C/C++ so I would not say this behavior is the same in Python as in C/C++

Comment: @Artur That's the difference between floored division vs standard divison, and modulus vs remainder operators. Floor and mod work towards negative infinity, standard division and remainder work toward zero.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 2.x, division works like it does in C-like languages: if both arguments are integers, the result is truncated to an integer, so 29/1009 is 0.  0 as a float is 0.0.  To fix it, cast to a float before dividing:

```
print str(float(numerator)/denominator)
```

In Python 3.x, the division acts more naturally, so you'll get the correct mathematical result (within floating-point error).

Answer (score 1):

In your evaluation you are casting the result, you need to instead cast the operands.

Answer (score 0):

```
print str(float(numerator)/float(denom))
```

Comment: It's sufficient to cast either of the operands to float().  I generally recommend casting the numerator as it locates the cast at the beginning of the expression where readers will normally see it more readily.

Comment: Yes it is, but this seemed more "proper" to me just because it was more transparent in its casting. But yes, casting one alone is enough.