# Python making sure x is an int, and not a pesky float

Tags: python

For example:

```
import random
x = random.randint(1, 6)
y = 2
new = x / y
...
```

now, lets say x turns out to be 5.
How can I catch if it's an int or a float before doing other things in my program?

Comment: Isnt the right way of doing this to find if there was a reminder or not ? - Yes, I am talking about the `%` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, integer division works a little unexpected in python 2, if you don't

```
from __future__ import division
```

Example:

```
>>> 5 / 3
1
>>> isinstance(5 / 3, int)
True
```

Explanation: [Why doesn’t this division work in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python/1787255#1787255)

Finally, you can always convert numbers to int:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> int(5/3)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want want `new` to always be an int, one option is floor division:

```
new = x // y
```

Another is to round:

```
new = int(round(x/y))
```

If instead, you just wanted to check if `new` is a float, that's a little unusual in Python (usually, type-checking isn't necessary). If so, tell us more about *why* you want to check and you'll get better guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(x, int)
```

But it's rare you need to do this.  Double-checking the standard library is probably not one of those times. :)

Note that you can also catch exceptions in some cases (though that wouldn't apply to this example).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the value being truncated (5.7 would become 5), you can simply cast it to an int.

```
must_be_an_int = int(x)
```

If for some reason x is something that python can't convert to an int, it will raise a ValueError exception.