# Basic python arithmetic - division

Tags: python, math, python-2.x

I have two variables : count, which is a number of my filtered objects, and constant value per_page. I want to divide count by per_page and get integer value but I no matter what I try - I'm getting 0 or 0.0 :

```
>>> count = friends.count()
>>> print count
1
>>> per_page = 2
>>> print per_page
2
>>> pages = math.ceil(count/per_pages)
>>> print pages
0.0
>>> pages = float(count/per_pages)
>>> print pages
0.0
```

What am I doing wrong, and why math.ceil gives float number instead of int ?

Comment: it works when I do it like this : count = float(count), per_page = float(per_page), pages = math.ceil(count/per_page) and finally pages = int(pages) . But that's a bit dumb way.

Comment: See [
Why doesn’t this division work in python?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python does integer division when both operands are integers, meaning that `1 / 2` is basically "how many times does 2 go into 1", which is of course 0 times. To do what you want, convert one operand to a float: `1 / float(2) == 0.5`, as you're expecting. And, of course, `math.ceil(1 / float(2))` will yield `1`, as you expect.

(I think this division behavior changes in Python 3.)

Answer (score 6):

Integer division is the default of the `/` operator in Python < 3.0. This has behaviour that seems a little weird. It returns the dividend without a remainder.

```
>>> 10 / 3
3
```

If you're running Python 2.6+, try:

```
from __future__ import division

>>> 10 / 3
3.3333333333333335
```

If you're running a lower version of Python than this, you will need to convert at least one of the numerator or denominator to a float:

```
>>> 10 / float(3)
3.3333333333333335
```

Also, math.ceil *always* returns a float...

```
>>> import math 
>>> help(math.ceil)

ceil(...)
    ceil(x)

    Return the ceiling of x as a float.
    This is the smallest integral value >= x.
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but it's the numerator, not nominator =]

Comment: I missed that in the docs focusing on the 'integer' part :P thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [Python documentation (math module)](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#number-theoretic-and-representation-functions):

> `math.ceil(x)`
>
> Return the ceiling of x as a float, the smallest integer value greater than or equal to x.

Answer (score 0):

They're integers, so `count/per_pages` is zero before the functions ever get to do anything beyond that. I'm not a Python programmer really but I know that `(count * 1.0) / pages` will do what you want. There's probably a right way to do that however.

*edit* — yes see @mipadi's answer and `float(x)`

Comment: Rather than multiplying by 1.0 everywhere, why don't you just use `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: I might do just that if I knew anything at all about Python :-)

Answer (score 0):

its because how you have it set up is performing the operation and then converting it to a float try

```
count = friends.count()
print count

per_page = float(2)
print per_page

pages = math.ceil(count/per_pages)

print pages
pages = count/per_pages
```

By converting either count or per_page to a float all of its future operations should be able to do divisions and end up with non whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 10 / float(3)
3.3333333333333335
>>> #Or 
>>> 10 / 3.0
3.3333333333333335
>>> #Python make any decimal number to float
>>> a = 3
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> b = 3.0
>>> type(b)
<type 'float'>
>>>
```

The best solution maybe is to use `from __future__ import division`