# Why I get this 0 as answer for (1/10) in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying this in Python 2.7 Interpreter.

```
>>> print 1/10  
0  
>>> print float(1/10)  
0.0  
>>> print 1/5  
0  
>>> a = 1/5  
>>> a  
0  
>>> float(a)  
0.0  
>>>
```

I want a value in floating point when I divide.  Any idea on the logic behind this zero out put and please let me know how to do it correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this division work in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The float conversion is happening **after** the integer division. Try this:

```
>>> print(1.0/10)
0.1
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, by default `/` means *integer* (truncating) division when used with two integer arguments. In Python 3.x, `/` always means *float* division, and `//` always means *integer* division. You can get the Python 3.x behaviour in 2.x using:

```
from __future__ import division
```

See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for a full discussion of the division operators.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like:

```
print (1.0/10)
```

When you do:

```
print 1/10
```

It is evaluating it as 0 because it is treating it as an integer.

And when you do:

```
print float(1/10)
```

You take the stuff inside the float() and evalute that first so in essence you get:

```
print float(0)
```

Which would be 0.0

Answer (score 1):

The integer division `1/10` returns an integer `0`. Converting integer `0` to float, just returns `0.0`. What you need to do is divide float and an integer to get a float. This will work.

```
>>> 1/10.0
0.1
```

or

```
>>> 1.0/10
0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Result of `integer` division is `integer`.

[From python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html)

> The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient
>   of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a
>   common type. Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the
>   same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the
>   ‘floor’ function applied to the result

Try

```
>>> 1.0/5
0.20000000000000001
>>> 1/5.0
0.20000000000000001
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the below:

```
(float (1)/10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Division in Python 2 between integers returns an integer result.  (In Python 3, it returns a float result as you might expect.)

To get a float result, convert at least one of the integers into a float:

```
>>> print(1/10)
0
>>> print(1/float(10))
0.1
>>> print(float(1)/10)
0.1
>>> print(float(1)/float(10))
0.1
```