# Python math output incorrect

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't this division work in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python)

A simple problem I'm having (I Think) The following statement:

```
    print (4950*8)/(((4950*8)/10000000*(1538/1460))+0.1/1000)/1000
```

Gives me 396000.0.

But on a Calculator I get 9270.614192621.

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong in the code that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old versions of Python use truncated integer division for `int` operands.

Try `from __future__ import division` (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/ for the full story) or coerce int operands to float (e.g. with `float`, or by appending `.0` to literals).

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> print (4950.0*8)/(((4950.0*8)/10000000*(1538.0/1460))+0.1/1000)/1000
9270.61419262
```