# Force Python calculation in double

Tags: python

I want to print a double in Python. But it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

My code:

```
test = 3000 / (1500 * 2000)
print str(test)
```

I always get a `0` and not a `0.001` even if I do the following:

```
test = 3000 / (1500 * 2000)
print '%.10f' % test
```

I get a `0.000000000` and not `0.001`.

How do I tell Python that this should be a double?

Comment: If you didn't use and old version of Python, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't call 2.x an 'old' version of Python

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.x you need to convert at least one of the operands to float, as integer division results in truncated output in Python 2.x:

```
>>> 3000 / (1500 * 2000)
0
>>> 3000.0 / (1500 * 2000) # Or use float(3000)
0.001
>>> float(3000) / (1500 * 2000)
0.001
```

Or you can import division of Python 3.x in Python 2.x, where integer division results in *true* division:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3000.0 / (1500 * 2000)
0.001
```

Note that this will affect the division in the whole module.

Comment: and how do I convert a len(MyList) to a float?

Comment: @gurehbgui use `float()`: `float( len(MyList) )`

Comment: Optionally `from future import true_division` if it won't break something else in the module

Comment: And another sort of work around is `from operator import truediv; x * truediv (y, z)`

Comment: @JonClements Didn't knew about `operator.truediv`.

Comment: Using `Decimal` will also work. +1 for `truediv` that was a new one for me.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you only used integer values at the math operation. Thus the result will be a (truncated) integer. If you want a float result, involve at least one float operand.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is fixed in Python 3.x. As pointed out in the other answers, the fix is to cast the divisible number to `float`.

If you want to make the `/` work as in Python 3.x, then you could do: `from __future__ import division`, and then you'll need to use the `//` operator to achieve the old behavior. You can check the Python documentation for information about [operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).