# Python: If key in dictA exist and key dictB do something

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have to compare two dictonaries (unsorted). Threfore I would iterate over one dictonary and If key is in dictA and dictB, then do something with the values. (for example dictA[key] / dict[B])

The dicts looks like:
total = {1951: 2, 1952: 2}
years = {1922: 33, 1951: 1}

I would except that ratio would be {1951 : 0.5} but instead it is empty.

I have tried various methods. The last one:

```
for i in total:
            if i in years:
                ratio[i] = years[i] / total[i]
```

I have also tried to use

```
year.viewkeys() | total.viewkeys()
```

But it would just return me the keys, I need to process the values. (Or at least I dont know how atm)

Comment: Could it be that you are using Python 2.x ? If so, check [why doesn't this division work in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python/1787255#1787255)

Comment: Yeah, python 2.7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find which keys are in both dictionaries using set intersection

```
>>> total = {1951: 2, 1952: 2}
>>> years = {1922: 33, 1951: 1}
>>> common = set(total.viewkeys()).intersection(years.viewkeys())
>>> common
{1951}
```

Then use a dict comprehension to calculate the ratios

```
>>> ratio = {i: float(years[i])/float(total[i]) for i in common}
>>> ratio
{1951: 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by "instead it is empty", you mean that `ratio` is `{1951: 0}`. If you're using Python 2.7, then it's using integer division: 1/2 is truncated down to zero. One possible solution is to convert to float before dividing.

```
total = {1951: 2, 1952: 2} 
years = {1922: 33, 1951: 1}
ratio = {}
for i in total:
    if i in years:
        ratio[i] = years[i] / float(total[i])

print ratio
```

Result:

```
{1951: 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year.viewkeys() | total.viewkeys()
```

is a very valid approach. try

```
commonkeys  = year.viewkeys() & total.viewkeys()
```

instead:

```
for key in commonkeys:
    ratio[key] = float(year[key]) / total[key]
```

notice that the `float` is necessary because in python2, `/` on integers will lead to `2/3==0`.